# How to edit the main menu text in mantis bug tracker

Tags: mantis, bug-tracker

I am trying to change the main menu text in the mantis bug tracker like "Report Issue" to "New Project" how can i accomplish this?

I looked at [`custom_strings_inc.php`](https://www.mantisbt.org/manual/admin.customize.status.html) but I could not understand how to change the main menu text from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to identify the correct lang variable name from the existing lang files (in **lang** folder) and override them in custom_strings.

For example, if you want to change **Report Issue** to **New Project**, edit **custom_strings_inc.php** and add the following line:

```
$s_report_bug_link = "New Project";
```